# How do you remove this green connection to a kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

How do I remove the green connector to the kitchen faucet. It has two tubes attached to it. Pfister has a one tube solution, but it does not work by twisting counterclockwise. No other brands has a similar quick connect. [image]

Comment: Appears that you squeeze the lower ends of the green bits inward, then pull down from what little can be seen in the picture. What brand of faucet is this - really doesn't matter "what Pfister has" if this isn't one, so that's a distraction...

Comment: @Ecnerwal Agree on squeezing the lower ends of the green tabs. It looks to me like you would then push the green tab/hose assembly up and out from the narrow black horizontal straps locking the tabs in place.

Comment: If you will not be reusing it, you could just cut through those plastic tubes.